# tmux: Remapping keys to pane on the left/right/top/down

Tags: tmux

Tmux allows one to move through panes using <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd> + <kbd>(→, ←, ↑, ↓)</kbd>.

I would like to remap this to:

<kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl-(l, j, i, k)</kbd>.

For reference, the layout of the keys <kbd>l,j,i,k</kbd> is similar to that of the arrow keys, but they are easier to type without moving the hand.

I have been editing a few things here and there on the `.tmux.conf`, but I could not find information on how to rebind the above commands.

Comment: `man tmux | less -p select-pane`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`tmux list-keys` (or `prefix + ?` in dfault settings) will give you current key mappings in the form of commands needed to set them up. See `man tmux`, the command name is `bind-key` (and you might want to remove the default bindings with `unbind-key`).

You might also want to consider more "standard" combination *hjkl*, known from `vi` and clones (all keys in the home row), especially if you are a fast typist.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to stick to vim-like navigation, would be useful to remap the `resize-pane` also:

```
# vim-like pane resizing  
bind -r C-k resize-pane -U
bind -r C-j resize-pane -D
bind -r C-h resize-pane -L
bind -r C-l resize-pane -R

# vim-like pane switching
bind -r k select-pane -U 
bind -r j select-pane -D 
bind -r h select-pane -L 
bind -r l select-pane -R 

# and now unbind keys
unbind Up     
unbind Down   
unbind Left   
unbind Right  

unbind C-Up   
unbind C-Down 
unbind C-Left 
unbind C-Right
```

I'll show you my `.tmux.conf` as a [reference](https://github.com/dminca/dotfiles/blob/master/dotfiles/.tmux.conf#L34-L62)

And by the way, don't forget to remap the `'horizontal-split'` in case you have it on the <kbd>h</kbd> key as it will interfere with your `pane-resize` and `pane-switch`.

Comment: Just a note: the "-r" allows you to do PREFIX then hit several times the command bound: for example:
`CTRL-B CTRL-J CTRL-J CTRL-J`
will extend the current pane by 3 lines instead of:
`CTRL-B CTRL-J CTRL-B CTRL-J CTRL-B CTRL-J`